# OpenCV 3.0 missing Libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2013, opencv3.0

I am trying to install OpenCV 3.0 Aplha. I'm following these instructions 
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html

After I download and extract the package, I am supposed to have all the pre-built libraries in the folder :opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib but I don't see them in this folder. This folder only has opencv_ts300.lib and opencv_world300.lib. All the other libraries seems to be missing. Also the bin folder doesn't have the dlls. But statlib folder does seems to have all the static libraries.

I also tried to build the libraries from source, and as per the instructions after building the OpeCVALL.sln in visual studio, I am supposed to have the libraries in the x86\vc12 but the libraries doesn't seem to be building in this folder. After digging through the folders I see that the opencv libraries are found in bin/debug and bin/release folders. I thought I would use these for linking in visual studio but I am not finding the header files in build/include folder

I don't see any of these issues with Opencv 2.49. Any help in debugging this issue with 3.0 would be highly appreciated.

Summary: After I build from source/ or pre-built package, I am able to run the sample applications. But I am not finding the headers and libraries to create a visual studio project from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured out what is going wrong here...
Build INSTALL project manually from the OpenCV.sln by right clicking - > build. This will create the libraries in build/install/x86/vc12 folder. This is where lib,bin and staticlib folders are now residing. Also the include files are in build/install/include.

Comment: After building yourself are the old libraries restored?  Or has the deployment model changed and now all functionality is cramped into two large libraries (world & ts)?

Answer (score -1):

Library files : located in your cmake folder's lib/debug(or release) folder

DLL files : located in cmake folder's bin/debug(or release) folder

Header files : located in opencv3's build/include folder

Comment: Library and DLL files are in the location mentioned by you. But header files are not. build/include folder has only cmake files and no headers.